# Varios onClick dentro de un switch

Tags: android-studio

Tengo el siguiente codigo de un compañero pero no entiendo ese metodo "pepitas" donde lo tiene demostrado, creo que hay que hacer algo en el xml, me paso las imagenes del .java pero no del xml entonces creo que hay que mover algo allí. he estado investigando pero sale distinto. alguna sugerencia?

```
public void pepitas(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnBuscar:
            consultarUsuario();
            break;
        case R.id.btnActualizar:
            actualizarUsuario();
            break;
        case R.id.btnEliminar:
            eliminarUsuario();
            break;

    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Rafa, agrega el código como texto no como imagen, esto será de mejor ayuda para que los miembros de la comunidad puedan analizar de una mejor forma tu código. saludos.

Comment: agrega la definición de tu Clase, es importante para explicar el método.

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo, no habia trabajado así ya que soy nuevo en esto. Lo unico que hay que hacer es nombrar en cada uno de los botones el metodo onClick con el nombre "pepitas" (referenciado al metodo que tiene el switch)

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEliminar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="pepitas"
            android:text="ELIMINAR" />
```